# Vim -- comment auto-wrapping messes up block insert

Tags: vim

I use vim's block insert to comment blocks of code like this (think of the square brackets as the cursor):

```
[k]eyword {
  variable declaration;
  return_type function_or_something() {
    for (a; b; c) {
      do_something_funky();
    }
}
```

Hit `Ctrl+V` `6jI//` `Space` `Esc`

```
[/]/ keyword {
//   variable declaration;
//   return_type function_or_something() {
//     for (a; b; c) {
//       do_something_funky();
//     }
// }
```

All nice and neat, but in this situation:

```
[k]eyword { // this is a block of code with a somewhat long comment
  variable declaration;
  return_type function_or_something() {
    for (a; b; c) {
      do_something_funky();
    }
}
```

Hit `Ctrl+V` `6jI//`, at this point the combination of `textwidth=80` and `formatoptions=caq1njw` kick in, and since my `//` has pushed the line over the textwidth, it triggers the wrap, and once that happens, my visual block insert operation is toast, so only the first line actually ends up getting commented out, and as a result I let loose a string of expletives.

```
[/]/keyword { // this is a block of code with a somewhat long
//comment
  variable declaration;
  return_type function_or_something() {
    for (a; b; c) {
      do_something_funky();
    }
}
```

Seems like a long shot, but I wonder if anyone knows of a workaround/fix... Maybe I can temporarily blow away `formatoptions` when I start a visual block selection? How to do that?

Note: I tried hitting `o` right before `I` to put the cursor at the bottom edge of the block selection, but it doesn't help, the way it works is once you hit `I` it will reposition the cursor to the top line, which subsequently screws you over as you turn the line into a comment.

Comment: I think it could help if you add the content of your `.vimrc`.

Comment: I already mentioned the relevant parts of my vimconfig. You can reproduce with vanilla vim with the two settings I mentioned. My .vimrc is 1337 lines long (happy coincidence, and yes, my vim is actually that badass), and you can find it at https://github.com/unphased/vim-config (The actual contents of this repo are a subset of my unix dotfiles)

Comment: Why not just move the long comment? Inline comments should be short and sweet. You may also want to look into a nice comment plugin. I use [commentary.vim](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/commentary-vim) but there are [others](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment).

Comment: Yeah i'm open to better solutions such as not using vim's autoformat for comments. Thanks for showing me vimawesome.com.

Comment: @PeterRincker the point was that the behavior is due to the length. If it was a regular code line that happened to be 79 chars long, my adding the `//` also results in this behavior

Answer (score 1):

Vim does not recognize code that is commented out and normal comments. I do not think such a thing exists. Your `'formatoptions'` specify that a inserted text in comments should reflow. You are inserting a comment so the comment will reflow. You can avoid this by not doing an insert but something else instead, like a substitution.

```
:s#^#//
```

However by far the easiest solution would be to use one of the many comment plugins. There are many options:  [commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) (which I use), [Nerd Commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter), [EnhCommentify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23), [tComment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim), ..., [etc](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment).